# Hide bulk actions from admin orders list except for processing status filtered list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, bulkupdate

Is there any way to hide bulk actions from admin orders list except for processing status filtered list: `post_status=wc-processing` where I only want to show bulk actions?

I tried to use code from *[How to remove bulk actions from admin orders page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72155239/how-to-remove-bulk-actions-from-admin-orders-page)*, but it hides bulk actions from all orders lists.

What I want is to show bulk actions only for Processing status filtered list. Is it possible?

Comment: Please add all necessary information to the question itself instead of links off-site. Asking us to go off-site and read/look for information just to be able to properly understand your question is asking too much. It also doesn't show us what your implementation/attempt looks like. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the following to only show bulk actions on "Processing" status orders list:

```
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'bulk_actions_only_on_processing_orders_list', 100 );
function bulk_actions_only_on_processing_orders_list( $bulk_actions ) {
    if( ! (isset($_GET['post_status']) && $_GET['post_status'] === 'wc-processing') ) {
        $bulk_actions = array();
    }
    return $bulk_actions;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin file). Tested and works.